# How to set landscape orientation on marmalade simulator?

Tags: android, lua, marmalade-quick

I just started developing an app with marmalade (https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/), and I'm having some issues with it's android simulator.

You see, I added the DispFixRot=FixedLandscape configuration to my app.icf config file, and the simulator still displays as Portrait.

My app.icf file:

```
[S3E]
MemMgrMaxAllocWarning=0
DispFixRot=FixedLandscape

[GL]

[QUICK]
mainFilename="main.lua"
```

How my simulator is showing:

[image]

What i'm doing wrong? How do I should change my simulator orientation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is still actual but you can change resolution (and orientation as result) in main menu `Configuration -> Surface... -> Predefined Resolution`